# What is NS5 brane?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, branes, supergravity

NS5 brane can be considered as [1/2 BPS solution](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201253v2)
 in supergravity (with other solutions to compare):

[image]

This branes of Type IIA/B supergravity are expected to extend to solutions of the full Type IIA/B string equations.

The NS5 brane indeed very much **behave as large size semi-classical solitons**, whose energy depends on the string coupling via $1/g^2_s$, as is familiar from solitons in quantum field theory.

In contrast, in the weak-coupling limit, the D-brane solution of supergravity reduces to a localized defect in flat space-time, that gives us boundary condition on the string dynamics.

But I wanna to understand more about NS5 branes.

1. What is **role of such objects in string theory**?
2. Which **d.o.f.** are related to such objects?
3. Is some **effective theory**, that describe dynamics of such objects? Is it Namby-Goto action for brane or some kind of DBI action?

Comment: This is really really broad. (Except for your question 3, which is immediately answered by a search for "ns5 brane effective action".)

Comment: @alexarvanitakis, could you answer in post with concrete formulas for actions and references? (Maybe I haven't enough knowledge to understand results of search)

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9806169 formula (2.10) for the NS5 brane on type IIB. First search hit, for me at least.